I am this getting error: Load balancer does not contain an instance for the service
I'm facing an intermittent "Load balancer does not contain an instance for the service CUSTOMER-SERVICE" error when calling my CustomerService from my ProxyService. The error occurs sporadically, but after a few retries, the request usually succeeds.
I've ensured that all services (Service Registry, Customer Service, and Proxy Service) are started in the correct order: Service Registry -> Customer Service -> Proxy Service.
error:
2024-12-13T10:54:38.884Z  WARN 3144 --- [proxy-service] [nio-9098-exec-1] o.s.c.l.core.RoundRobinLoadBalancer      : No servers available for service: CUSTOMER-SERVICE
2024-12-13T10:54:38.891Z  WARN 3144 --- [proxy-service] [nio-9098-exec-1] .s.c.o.l.FeignBlockingLoadBalancerClient : Load balancer does not contain an instance for the service CUSTOMER-SERVICE
2024-12-13T10:54:38.899Z ERROR 3144 --- [proxy-service] [nio-9098-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed: feign.FeignException$ServiceUnavailable: [503] during [POST] to [http://CUSTOMER-SERVICE/customer/auth/sign-in] [CustomerService#login(LoginRequest)]: [Load balancer does not contain an instance for the service CUSTOMER-SERVICE]] with root cause

feign.FeignException$ServiceUnavailable: [503] during [POST] to [http://CUSTOMER-SERVICE/customer/auth/sign-in] [CustomerService#login(LoginRequest)]: [Load balancer does not contain an instance for the service CUSTOMER-SERVICE]

Relevant Configurations:
Proxy-Service application.yml
spring:
  application:
    name: proxy-service

eureka:
  client:
    service-url:
      default-zone: http://localhost:8761/eureka
    fetch-registry: true

Customer-Service application.yml
spring:
  application:
    name: customer-service

eureka:
  client:
    service-url:
      default-zone: http://localhost:8761/eureka

Service-Registry application.yml
spring:
  application:
    name: service-registry

server:
  port: 8761

eureka:
  client:
    register-with-eureka: false
    fetch-registry: false

Environment:

Java: 17
Spring Boot: 3.4.0
Spring Cloud: 2024.0.0

Additional Information:

I've tried restarting the services multiple times.
The issue seems to be intermittent, as sometimes the requests succeed without any issues.

Request for Help:
I'm seeking guidance on potential causes for this intermittent error and effective troubleshooting strategies. Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
